# What a kind of this For-In loop is?

Tags: python, scripting, maya, for-in-loop

I'm trying to figure out someone's Maya scripting, which is Python. 
but I have never seen like this kind of `for loop` before. I just want to know why he declares two variables? And I also removed variable and changed both of names, but it didn't work. It's a part of this scripting:

```
if len( self.targetObj ) == 1:

    self.txT= self.targetObj[ 0 ]           
    actVertics = mc.polyEvaluate( v = True )
    returnText = self.txT + "( " + str( actVertics ) + " )"
    mc.textField( "targetObj", edit = True, tx = returnText )
    self.vtxList = [ v for v in range( actVertics ) ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Shortly, it creates a list from range(actVertics) elements. Look for python list comprehensions for more information.